# About style images in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, styles

Hi I'm styling a small website and it renders perfectly on IE9 Crome and Firefox. But not in IE8. te images do not feet on the design and they go off-limits.
html fragments:

```
<div id="MainImage1"><img src="Stores/DigitalExperience/ArticleImages/mainBanner.jpg" border="0" width="100%"></div>
<div id="product-table">
<div id="product1" class="product-column">
<a href="Main.asp?D=%7BF526E79F%2D78C3%2D4703%2D9CF5%2D4CEF53FCD0D7%7D&amp;PageType=Product&amp;SKU=GAL-I9190-WHT"><img src="Stores/DigitalExperience/ProductImages/S4MINIWHT_small.jpg" valign="middle" border="0">&nbsp;SAMSUNG GALAXY S4-WHITE</a>   
</div>
<div id="product2" class="product-column">
<a href="Main.asp?D=%7BF526E79F%2D78C3%2D4703%2D9CF5%2D4CEF53FCD0D7%7D&amp;PageType=Product&amp;SKU=GAL-I9500-BLK"><img src="Stores/DigitalExperience/ProductImages/s4-i9500_small.jpg" valign="middle" border="0">&nbsp;GALAXY SAMSUNG S4 BLK</a>
</div>
<div id="product3" class="product-column">
<a href="Main.asp?D=%7BF526E79F%2D78C3%2D4703%2D9CF5%2D4CEF53FCD0D7%7D&amp;PageType=Product&amp;SKU=UA32F5500-1-000"><img src="Stores/DigitalExperience/ProductImages/UA32F5500_small.jpg" valign="middle" border="0">&nbsp;32 INCH LED TV</a>
</div>
```

then the CSS that styles this code is this:

```
#MainImage1 {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #0000ff;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 25px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
margin: 0;
padding:0;   
}
#product-table{
display: table;
}

#product-table .product-column {
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 25px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #0000ff;
display: table-cell; 
width: 30%; 
padding: 10px; 
}
#product-table .product-column:nth-child(even) { 
background: #ccc;
}
#product-table .product-column:nth-child(odd) { 
background: #eee;
}
TD.MainAreaText img {
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 25px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
position: relative;
}
```

any Idea about how to make this code render decently in IE8, I do not need the round border for now in IE8, I Only need that the website images feet in the design.
Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Install chrome frame and try,

http://www.google.com/chromeframe?prefersystemlevel=true

Comment: What about the users from other places? they have to install it also to see my website? I need to style my website in a way that it looks decent in internet explorer 8. I do not need the round borders.

Answer (score 0):

you need use the a polyfill like css3 pie. here is the link http://css3pie.com/demos/border- radius/

Comment: My problem is not with the border sorry about adding them in this post. My problem is with the images going out of the place where they are supposed to be... I mean going out a lot, around half image outside the place where they where supposed to be.

Comment: use  float left to children divs with correct div.  and parent div make it as positon relative with totall box width of three divs. and also add overflow hidden to perent div. if you send me the fiddle i can help you more

Answer (score 0):

border-radius just work in CSS3 supported browser. IE8 does not support it. So the corners will go off-limits.

This may help you to fix this issue: http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: My problem is not with the border sorry about adding them in this post. My problem is with the images going out of the place where they are supposed to be... I mean going out a lot, around half image outside the place where they where supposed to be.

Comment: could I visit you page? I need more detail

Comment: Hi the web is not online, the site is a web-shop provided by Pastel (a company that sells software pre-made). I have access to  change the CSS only, add some javascript, content and images, I can post somewhere the whole CSS and the HTML, maybe that will work?

Comment: of cause you can. please attach the images as well

Comment: This compresed file has the web page saved [link](http://www.abelworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/aa.tar.gz) I have noticed that using IE8 in big screens only the background appears to be wrong (smaller), but in small screens all the images keep a bigger size than what they should.

Comment: Hi Able, you forgot to add attribute width="100%" to three small images. And you'd better remove height: 1% in line 220 of css file custom.css as well.

Comment: Hi Able, did they work? If they work, do not forgot to close the question.

Comment: I have notices that ths is happening only in small resolution screens like mini laptops with IE8. About ur comment: the 1% was and advise from someone some where else... but it was doing it before and the big image is going a lot bigger than the screen in small resolutions , I will try and let you know. Thank you.